# Php: avoiding function being treated as string

Tags: php, escaping

I want to treat the contents of a website as a string, and assign to a variable.

However, if I write `<?php $stringvariable = ' include https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/USER.rss ' ?>`

php will assume that the include function, and the address contained within, are merely a string.

Is there some way to avoid this?

P.S. I'll probably be actually using the function `read_file` as a basic security measure in the really unlikely event that the RSS feed from which I'm reading gets hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$stringvariable = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/USER.rss');
```

DO NOT USE `INCLUDE` FOR THIS PURPOSE!

**PLEASE NOTE**

Include is NOT a function - it is control structure!
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$variable = file_get_contents(URL)
```